# "asking us to recommend or find"... reason for putting a SO Q on hold

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Consider for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708325/check-how-two-string-ressemble-in-python?noredirect=1#comment43829077_27708325 -- a typical "how do I perform task X in language Y" question.

It's been put on hold as "asking us to recommend or find" (a tool, book, library, &c), while it's asking no such thing -- rather, it's asking how to perform a certain task.

It just so happens that answers may involve recommending a library, or a module within language Y's standard library (both, in this Q's case), rather than showing algorithms for X implemented in Y -- but, how does the nature of such answers (which the querant can't know in advance) retroactively disqualify the question?

It seems to me that closing reason should only apply to questions **specifically** asking for recs of off-site resources, rather than otherwise perfectly acceptable ones which **happen** to have, among their acceptable answers, such recs, no?

Comment: It would have been better if he specifically said "the Python standard library".  But his question just said "a Python module".  This leaves the door open for *anything* that can be considered a Python module (standard modules, 3rd-party modules, personal modules, etc.)

Comment: You've been away for a while, things changed.  The Close dialog was whittled down to very specific close reasons, the community compensated by giving what was left a more liberal interpretation.

Comment: Here's a similar post regarding a different specific-question, but the answer is very applicable: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260713/how-is-this-question-asking-to-find-a-tool-or-an-off-site-resource?rq=1

Answer (score 9):

The question was closed because it specifically asks for a module:

> **I am looking for a Python module**,  or at least, a way to find how close 2 strings resemble.

However, the question is also *very broad*. By what criteria should the strings be compared? What research has the author done into comparison approaches, what would work for their use case, and what won't?

What the question then will attract is everyones favourite approach, each with different pros and cons. Which one would be better than another, for what specific usecases? By what criteria should they be measured? Runtime cost, memory cost, effectiveness for specific corner cases, etc.?

Those issues would need to be addressed before the question could be re-opened.

Comment: OK, edited from "a module, or at least a way" to just "a way" -- doesn't seem to me that this is any true improvement, but it does address the specific issue (and a Q did need a little improvement in English grammar anyway).  "Too broad", maybe -- that's a completely different reason and I would not object to it (nor could I fix it -- only the OP for example knows the use case).

Comment: @AlexMartelli: the question wasn't great. I got to pick from two options here, and I picked the recommendation reason this time. Looks like the majority of voters picked that same reason. It remains, in my opinion, a low quality question for which there may well be better-worded dupes.